# Chrome stops video execution

Tags: video.js

Using IE everything goes well (i got a mp4 video with priority execution setted on flash). when i try to view my video on chrome all seem to be good too, but in few seconds (not always but often) videojs crashes.
    This is the log:

```
error:MediaError
    code:3
```

What should i do?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. If you already resolve this issue, please share your answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#dom-mediaerror-media_err_decode) error code `MEDIA_ERR_DECODE = 3` means that video was failed to be decoded. Chrome could reach broken frame e.g. video was encoded incorrectly.

In my experience HTML5 video decoding has poor support when it comes to error handling. Flash is more bullet-proof here. I got an example when Chrome (HTML5) failed to play video but it was playing fine in FF (flash). Converting to different pixel map (`yuvj420p` -> `yuv420p`) resolved my issue.

It means that first you should try encoding video with different options. As an option you can use `ffmpeg`